# Copy additional dll while publishing web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I'm developing web service that and later publish it using VS wizard. My service uses external dll that also should be published. How to tell system to publish dll to web services `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you add reference to your external dlls and use anything inside the dll, that dll will be automatically copied to the `bin` folder together with your dll.

In case your dlls are loaded dynamically, you can try adding this to your `.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="AdditionalPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
        <Copy SourceFiles="" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Specify `SourceFiles` with what you want to publish: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

For example, let's say you want to copy these dlls:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ExternalFiles Include="lib1.dll;lib2.dll;lib3.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AdditionalPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(ExternalFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"
    />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you publish VS has created  *.pubxml file inside your Properties folder, for example I am using VS 2015 for MVC 4.5 and below is my location where my *.pubxml file is found.

[image: pubxml]

You can edit this xml file as explained in [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying Extra Files](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files) and add your extra DLLs folder here.